# postgres sql bucket values into generated time sequence

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to transform data from a table of recorded events. I am transforming the data into a consistent 'daily half hour view'. e.g 48 half periods (padding out half hours with zero when there are no matching events), i have completed this with partial success.

```
SELECT t1.generate_series, 
v1.begin_time,
v1.end_time,
v1.volume
FROM tbl_my_values v1
 RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT generate_series.generate_series
       FROM generate_series((to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-dd'::text) || ' 22:00'::text)::timestamp without time zone, 
       (to_char(now() + '1 day'::interval, 'YYYY-MM-dd'::text) || ' 22:00'::text)::timestamp without time zone, '00:30:00'::interval) 
       generate_series(generate_series)) t1 ON t1.generate_series = v1.begin_time
       order by 1 ;
```

This provides the following results:

```
2015-12-19 22:00:00 | 2015-12-19 22:00:00+00 | 2015-12-19 23:00:00+00 | 172.10
2015-12-19 22:30:00 |                        |                        |
2015-12-19 23:00:00 | 2015-12-19 23:00:00+00 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00+00 | 243.60
2015-12-20 00:30:00 |                        |                        |
2015-12-20 01:00:00 |                        |                        |
```

However based on the 'start' and 'end' columns the view should be:

```
2015-12-19 22:00:00 | 2015-12-19 22:00:00+00 | 2015-12-19 23:00:00+00 | 172.10
2015-12-19 22:30:00 |                        |                        | 172.10
2015-12-19 23:00:00 | 2015-12-19 23:00:00+00 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00+00 | 243.60
2015-12-20 00:30:00 |                        |                        | 243.60
2015-12-20 01:00:00 |                        |                        |
```

because the the values in this example span 2 half hours e.g. are valid for one hour.
All help is very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ON` clause is only comparing to the `begin_time`.  I think you want an inequality:

```
on t1.generate_series between v1.begin_time and t1.end_time
```

Comment: Actually just working through results the between is duplicating an extra row, e.g. creating 2 * 23:00 row above, because it is matching on both begin and end time I presume.

Comment: So the query is correctly bucketing the values but generating a duplicate row.

Comment: Found a work-around for this example. It is to use between start and (end minus 1 minute)